# How is it possible next statement to be true?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
sdata = {'Ohio': 35000, 'Texas': 71000, 'Oregon': 16000, 'Utah': 5000}
obj1 = pd.Series(sdata)
states = ['California', 'Ohio', 'Oregon', 'Texas']
obj2 = pd.Series(sdata, index=states)
obj3 = pd.isnull(obj2)
```

How is it possible next statement to be true?

```
x = obj2['California']
obj2['California'] != x
```

Comment: Did you expect `obj3 = pd.isnull(obj2)` to do something to `obj2`? It doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing two `nan` values.  Your comparison `!=` is implemented as `not ==`.
A defining property of `nan` is that it will fail *any* comparison.  Therefore, `nan == nan` is `False`, resulting in your `True` value.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the def of `nan`

```
np.nan != np.nan
Out[68]: True
```